# "warning: use of old-style cast" in g++

Tags: c++, casting, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

With this C++ code,

```
char* a = (char*) b;
```

I got warning `warning: use of old-style cast`.

What would be the new-style cast?

Comment: Well, what is `b`?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast`, `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` and `const_cast` are the c++ cast alternatives.

- `const_cast` to remove const/volatile from a const variable.
- `dynamic_cast` to perform runtime validity checks when casting in between polymorphic types
- `static_cast` to perform e.g up/down-cast in a inheritance hierarchy, but with no runtime checks, or to explicitly perform conversions that could be implicit (e.g. float to int)
- `reinterpret_cast` to convert in between unrelated types.

Brief syntax example:

```c++
char* a = (char*) b; 
//would be 
char* a = static_cast<char*>(b);
//to remove the warning
```

Answer (score 3):

Read this topic to know about C++ style casts which come in various flavors:

[When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: I would argue that, if you think a link to another question is a suitable answer, then the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Chris: After posting, I realized that. So I voted for closing it!

Comment: Depends, could he find the other question by searching for "old-style" and/or "new-style" cast?

Comment: @Erik: it doesn't depend, since if this question is marked a duplicate, it still stands as a search landing page. If it's a dupe, it should be marked a dupe, not answered again with identical answers just because the question is worded a bit differently.

Comment: Ahh ok, then I'll vote to close as well.