# Random real in [0..1[ using Mersenne Twister

Tags: c++, random, prng, mersenne-twister

I'm trying to make a model of a zombie apocalipse in c++ using simple structs and a when I'm randomizing the population, I need some fields of the struct to have a value in the interval [0..1[. As I'm interested in a more statistically correct analysis, I choose to use the mt19937 engine to generate my "data". When playing around with this PRNG I couldn't find a way to generate a number in said range. Here's the code that I came up with:

```
int
main ( int argc, char** argv )
{

    mt19937_64 newr ( time ( NULL ) );
    std::cout << newr.max ( ) << endl;
    std::cout << newr.min ( );
    double rn;
    for(;;){
        rn = newr()/newr.max ();
        std::cout << rn << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But the only outputs that I get for the loop are zeros (0). A small print of the output is down:

```
18446744073709551615
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `std::uniform_real_distribution`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the return value of `newr()` and `newr.max()` are integers and the value returned by `newr()` is *smaller* than `newr.mar()`. The result of the division is a zero integer which is *then* converted to a `double`. To fix this use

```
rn = static_cast<double>(newr()) / newr.max();
```

Comment: Thank You so much, as soon as i can, i'll mark this as the correct answer. I should have thought of this earlier lol.

Comment: Would be better to do a `static_cast<double>(foo)`, probably.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Just to be idomatic, sure ;p

Comment: I think newer versions of clang++ will choke on `(double)foo`-style casting. The `static_cast` approach may be more future-proof. YMMV.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: why would they choke on valid C++ code?

Comment: Also, whats the difference of using static_cast<double> and just (double). Doesn't GCC (the compiler i'm using) compiles both the same way?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps choke is too strong. That kind of casting can raise a “warning: use of old-style cast” compilation warning. Warnings are generally useful to fix. Pedro, the following SO question and answer succinctly explains C++-style casting, including `static_cast<>`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5249436/19410

Comment: The following SO answer goes into more detail about old-style ("C") casts and why it is a good idea to get into the habit of avoiding them in C++ code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/19410

Comment: @Pedro this will not give a uniform distribution, in particular `1.0` is extremely less likely to occur than any other bit combination. Any reason you're not using the standard library wrappers for this?

Comment: @MarkRansom AFIC the mt19937 should give a much more uniform distribution the standard 'rand()'. I think I've got some deficits on my C/C++ learning, what are the wrappers?

Comment: @Pedro I'm talking about the classes in the `<random>` header, they're meant to be used with `mt19937`. In particular [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution). The problem is not in the distribution of the engine but in the way they are mapped to the range. `uniform_real_distribution` sidesteps the problem by excluding the end of the range altogether.

Comment: @MarkRansom As I was reading the documentation for those classes, I got a little bit confused, and tried to keep it simple. This is just a personal project. My next step is to make GSL work in my windows machine, then I'll just use the normal distribution of the GSL. But thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 3):

You divide `int` by `int` and so have integer rounding.

A way to use the random engine is by one of the various distributions,
in your case `std::uniform_real_distribution`:

```
std::mt19937_64 engine ( time ( NULL ) );
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0., 1.);
for(;;){
    const double rn = dist(engine);
    std::cout << rn << std::endl;
}
```